# Why are images black when saved even though array is not black?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to save black and white images from a `6 x 6` array, that I have imported, but the images are saving as completely black, even though the array has sections in the middle that greater than 0.

```py
import scipy.io
from PIL import Image

importedImageList = [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0.32941176, 0.87058824, 0.2627451, 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0.7254902, 0.99607843, 0.44705882, 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0.62352941, 0.99607843, 0.28235294, 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0.59215686, 0.99607843, 0.44705882, 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0.23529412, 0.99607843, 0.63921569, 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0.23921569, 0.4745098, 0.4745098, 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0.14117647, 0.94509804, 0.89019608, 0.06666667, 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0.12156863, 0.52156863,
                      0.94901961, 0.99607843, 0.99607843, 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.77647059, 0.99607843, 0.25882353, 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.01176471, 0.14901961, 0.87843137, 0.99607843,
                      0.99607843, 0.99607843, 0.81176471, 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.77647059, 0.88235294, 0.05490196, 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0.0745098, 0.79607843, 0.99607843, 0.99607843, 0.99607843,
                      0.99607843, 0.85882353, 0.07058824, 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.77647059, 0.99607843, 0.2627451, 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0.29411765, 0.86666667, 0.99607843, 0.99607843, 0.45098039, 0.20392157,
                      0.20392157, 0.15686275, 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.77647059, 0.99607843, 0.2627451, 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0.03529412, 0.49411765,
                      0.98431373, 0.99607843, 0.85882353, 0.30196078, 0.00392157, 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.77647059, 0.99607843, 0.2627451, 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.23137255, 0.52156863, 0.80392157,  0.99607843,
                      0.94117647, 0.65098039, 0.1372549, 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.77647059, 0.98039216, 0.23137255, 0.,
                      0.08627451, 0.50588235, 0.97647059, 0.99607843, 0.97254902, 0.71372549,
                      0.22352941, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.77647059, 0.89803922, 0.08235294, 0.3254902,
                      0.91372549, 0.99607843, 0.99607843, 0.73333333, 0.22745098, 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.77647059, 0.99607843, 0.9254902, 0.99215686,
                      1., 0.93333333, 0.24313725, 0.01960784, 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.66666667, 0.99607843, 0.99607843, 0.81960784,
                      0.3254902, 0.17254902, 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0.20392157, 0.54901961, 0.41568627, 0.07058824,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ],
                     [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
                      0., 0., 0., 0., ]]

importedImage = np.array(importedImageList)
print(importedImage)

img = Image.fromarray(importedImage, '1')
img.save('my.png')
img.show()
```

The image is just completely black, but there should be a large round spot in the center. After following advice, I can now see some light, but the print out of the image should be a number (7), but is instead all lumped at the bottom of the printed image.

Comment: when I try to run it then I get error because `importedImage` is not normal list

Comment: when I add value 255 then I can see while element. Maybe it doesn't use values `0...1` but `0...255` so values 0...1 are black

Comment: OR maybe it need mode `I` (upper i), not `1` - see [modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)

Comment: my actual code uses a section of imported data: importedImage = importedData[12,:,:]   When I print importedImage it comes out as I have listed in the code above. I will edit above so that that section works for you as it works for me.

Comment: The "I" does show the image, but the image is off, all the light values are neat the bottom of the image..

Comment: [modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) shows that `pil` works rather with integer values - 0...255. For `1` it uses every bit in byte as white or black but all your float values probably are rounded to `0` so all pixels are black.

Comment: I have changed it to see some light, but the image is completely off for some reason - please see my edits.

Answer (score 1):

You have a single channel floating point image, and apparently the columns of your image are stored in that list. To obtain the desired image, the following code might be helpful:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

importedImageList = [[ ... ]]

# Transpose resulting array, because columns are stored in the list
importedImage = np.array(importedImageList).T

# Show image, explicitly set scale 0 ... 1
plt.imshow(importedImage, vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='gray')
plt.colorbar()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Explicitly convert to range 0 ... 255 and uint8 type for saving
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(importedImage * 255))
img.save('my.png')
```

The plot looks like this:

[image: Plot]

And that's the saved image:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
Matplotlib:  3.2.0rc3
NumPy:       1.18.1
Pillow:      7.0.0
----------------------------------------
```